# Laravel Database Query Error

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I`m new to the laravel 5.4 and um developing trainee management system.what i need is when i press see details button on right side green color.all the datas under the that Trainee id need to be shown.see the image,
[image]

for an example if i want to see ID MOB/TR/1739.i need to press see details on right side.hope you got it.in additionally here is the database related to that.

[image]

Here is i developed controller for that.

```
public function user_details($traninee_id)
{
    $trainee_details= registerdetails::where('traninee_id','=',$traninee_id)->get()->first();
     return view('registeredusers.seedetails', compact('trainee_details'));
}
```

Here is the error um getting.[image]

Can anyone suggest me the suggestions to complete it?

Comment: can you show us your route?

Comment: Please show the route you're trying to use and how do you generate link to this route.

Comment: Route::get('Seedetails', 'UserRegisterController@user_details');

Comment: Try this: Route::get('Seedetails/{id}', 'UserRegisterController@user_details');

Comment: i changed but ir dost work

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the `traninee_id` in your route so to fix this update your route to this

```
Route::get('Seedetails/{id}', 'UserRegisterController@user_details');
```

And assuming that you're using `$traninee` to display the content of table so update your `See Here` button with this

```
<a href="Seedetails/{{ $traninee->traninee_id }}">See Here</a>
```

Comment: Sir i change the code but it give error again route error.that means route is not going to work

Comment: @Dasun please show me your `seedetails.blade.php` and also which error?

Comment: Sir i`m place it as a new question rather than editing this question.i ll mention you their.

Answer (score 0):

The error says there is a problem with the route you use. So add an ID to the route:

```
Route::get('Seedetails/{traineeId}', 'UserRegisterController@user_details');
```

And pass the ID when you create a link to this route:

```
url('Seedetails/'.$traineeId)
```

Comment: Sir i change the route but i dont understand how to create a link passing ID.can you please explain bit?

Comment: @Dasun I've shown how in my answer (the `url()` helper). You also can name your route and use `route()` helper like `<a href="{{ route('your.route.name', ['traineeId' => $traineeId]) }}"></a>`

Comment: sir as um new to laravel i didnt get what you are saying.sorry

Comment: Then you should really read the routing docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing